# Nestjs - aceptar validación DTO y body

Tags: nestjs

Tengo una app conectada a MongoDB, y necesito que al crear una nueva instancia del schema se valide sus propiedades y además cualquier otro valor que llegue por el body. Es decir, validar el DTO y también aceptar propiedades fuera de este.

Probé agregando `skipMissingProperties: true` en el main de forma global pero aún no toma valores que no estén en el schema.

```
app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      skipMissingProperties: true,
    }),
  );
```

Es posible aceptar valores especificados en un schema y además cualquier otro valor fuera de el? en el @Post del controller se debe enviar el dto junto con el body: any?

Espero que se haya entendido la consulta.
Desde ya gracias!

Comment: No entiendo bien la consulta, lo que estás buscando es que puedas pasarle valores a un schema DTO que no están declarados en el propio DTO?

Comment: Hola Javier, gracias por responder. Por suerte ya pude solucionarlo, pero si, es como comentabas. Lo que buscaba era validar propiedades ya definidas en el schema y cualquier otro valor que llegue por el body, que es justamente lo que impide Nest por default pero era lo que necesitaba hacer. Dejo la respuesta más abajo.

Answer (score 0):

Para futuros lectores, se debe agregar la propiedad `strict: false` en el decorador Schema. De esa forma aceptará valores fuera del mismo esquema.

Quedando así:

```
@Schema({ strict: false })
```